# Solving $\int^{2\pi}_0 d\theta \ln\left(\sqrt{1 - a^2\cos^2\theta} + ia\cos\theta\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, vector-analysis

I'm trying to take the following integral. 
$$I = \int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \ln\left[\sqrt{1 - (\hat{\rho}\cdot\vec{a})^2} + i\hat{\rho}\cdot\vec{a}\right],$$
where $\hat{\rho} = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is the unit vector in polar coordinates, and $\vec{a} = (a_x,a_y) = \Vert a \Vert(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ is some arbitrary vector, and it is known that $a \equiv \Vert\vec{a}\Vert < 1$. We can choose $\phi=0$, such that
$$ I = \int^{2\pi}_0 d\theta \ln\left(\sqrt{1 - a^2\cos^2\theta} + ia\cos\theta\right).$$

I have tried change of variables, factorization etc, but get nowhere. Is there any hope of being able to solve it?

Comment: Is $\|\vec a\| \le 1$? When it is greater than $1$, the whole character of this problem changes. In any case, rewrite $\vec a = \|a\|(\cos\phi, \sin\phi)$. It will accomplish a useful reduction of complexity.

Comment: Yes, it is in fact true that $\Vert\vec{a}\Vert < 1$ (strictly smaller than).

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can assume $\phi = 0$.

Comment: @fromGiants Looks like you have lost interest in your integral?~!

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc no I was just not sure about the rewriting of the integral in your solution, namely when you split the integrand into two logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} ln[\sqrt{1-a^2\cos^2 x}+ai \cos x]~ dx= 2\int_{0}^{\pi} ln[\sqrt{1-a^2\cos^2 x}+ai \cos x]~ dx.$$
Next use $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx= \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx$. Then
$$2I=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\left( \ln[\sqrt{1-a^2\cos^2 x}+ai \cos x]+\ln[\sqrt{1-a^2\cos^2 x}-ai \cos x]\right)~ dx.$$
$$2I=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln[ 1-a^1\cos^2 x+ a^2 \cos^2 x]~dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \ln 1 ~dx =0$$
Hence $$I=0.$$